# getting Error while ef core seeding the data

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

Below is my seed class..

```
   public static class DataInitializer
    {
        public static async void SeedRolesAsync(RoleManager<Role> roleManager)
        {
            if (roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Administrator").Result)
                return;

            var role = new Role
            {
                Name = "Administrator",
                Description = "Perform all the operations."
            };
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);


        }

        public static async void SeedRoleClaimsAsync(RoleManager<Role> roleManager)
        {



            var role = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Administrator");


            var roleClaims = await roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);

            foreach (var claimString in AllClaims.GetList())
            {
                var newClaim = new Claim(claimString, "");
                if (!roleClaims.Any(rc => rc.Type.ToString() == claimString))
                {
                    await roleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, newClaim);
                }
            }
        }

        public static async void SeedUsersAsync(UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                UserName = "admin@example.com",
                Email = "admin@example.com",
                FirstName = "Admin",
                LastName = "User",
                Enabled = true
            };
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Admin@123");
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Administrator");
            }
        }

        public static void SeedData(UserManager<User> userManager, RoleManager<Role> roleManager)
        {
            SeedRolesAsync(roleManager);
            SeedRoleClaimsAsync(roleManager);
            SeedUsersAsync(userManager);
        }
    }
```

calling this method in startup class  `DataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager);`

Am getting error  below  error while seeding.. i am using  ef core 3 for postgresql..  Am getting

System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'MyUserManager'.'

[image]

Comment: You should be returning tasks and awaiting them all the way up. Don't return `void` from `async` methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void Please show the code where you are calling `DataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager);` in your `Startup.cs` file.

Comment: public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, UserManager<User> userManager, RoleManager<Role> roleManager)
        {  DataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager); }

Comment: Thanks am calling last line inside configure method ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using tasks all the way - if you don't return anything to wait on chances are the code will continue with disposal even when something hasn't completed yet.

```cs
public static async Task SeedData(UserManager<User> userManager, RoleManager<Role> roleManager)
{
    await SeedRolesAsync(roleManager);
    await SeedRoleClaimsAsync(roleManager);
    await SeedUsersAsync(userManager);
}

public static async Task SeedRolesAsync(RoleManager<Role> roleManager)
{
    ⋮
}

public static async Task SeedRoleClaimsAsync(RoleManager<Role> roleManager)
{
    ⋮
}

public static async Task SeedUsersAsync(UserManager<User> userManager)
{
    ⋮
}
```

You can also move this call into the `Main` method of your `Program.cs` because that method can be made `async`.

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    using (var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>())
    using (var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<Role>>())
    {
        await DataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    await host.RunAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```